# How can I force intercept to be 1 within PROC SGPANEL?

Tags: sas

In a linear regression I would like the line to go through (0,1) i.e. I want to force/restrict the intercept parameter to be 1. This is preferably done using a REG statement within a PROC SGPANEL (since I want to display multiple regression lines in the same plot, alternatives are, however, very much appreciated)

The syntax is:

```
PROC SGPANEL DATA=...;
 PANELBY ...;
 REG Y=... X=... / ...;
RUN;
```

I don't think that the RESTRICT statement works here. So what can I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is almost certainly a bad idea. However, if you insist on it, then I think the only way is to do the regressions for each panel with the restrictions, make new variables that consist of X and Y variables for each strata, then use those values in PROC SGPANEL with the LINEPARM statement.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to force the intercept to be any particular value in a regression.  See  [this thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102709/when-forcing-intercept-of-0-in-linear-regression-is-acceptable-advisable) and links from there

Comment: Well, but in this particular case it makes sense. However, thanks for the warning.